# How to return array again to a string without exclamation marks in javascript

Tags: javascript

I actually tried to replace string values

```js
const MyFunc = (str) => {
  arr = str.toString()
  for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    arr[i] = arr[i].replace('!', '.')
  }

  arr = arr.toString()
  return arr
}

console.log(MyFunc('Mening yurtim ! Men juda faxirlanaman !'));
```

Comment: but this is giving me     but this is giving me    M,e,n,i,n,g, ,y,u,r,t,i,m, ,., ,m,e,n, ,j,u,d,a, ,h,a,m,

Comment: Use `string.replaceAll()` method of JS. `'Mening yurtim ! Men juda faxirlanaman !'.replaceAll('!', '.')`

Comment: Use `join('')`.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you are trying to do? I'm not sure why you were calling .toString() on something that was already a string. You also don't need to change strings to an array to iterate over them. you can just run the for loop on the str.length if you would prefer.

```js
const MyFunc = (str) => {
  return str.replace(/!/g, '.')
}

console.log(MyFunc('Mening yurtim ! Men juda faxirlanaman !'))
```

If you look at the documentation on string.replace() In order for it to change every value in the string for you , you have to pass it the string you would like to replace like this.

`/what you want to replace/g`

If you want to ignore case sensitivity you would do it like this

`/what you want to replace/gi`

[Hope this helps!](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `string.replaceAll()` method to make this task cleaner ! [See MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replaceAll)

See =>

```
const MyFunc = (str) => {
   str = str.replaceAll('!','.');
  return str;
};

console.log(MyFunc('Mening yurtim ! Men juda faxirlanaman !'));
```

Comment: @Azizbek Mukhtorov Does this solves your problem ?

Answer (score 0):

**use** `replaceAll`**:**

```js
console.log('Mening yurtim ! Men juda faxirlanaman !'.replaceAll('!', '.')); // Mening yurtim . Men juda faxirlanaman .



let text = 'Mening yurtim ! Men juda faxirlanaman !';
let replaced = text.replaceAll('!', '.');
console.log(replaced); // Mening yurtim . Men juda faxirlanaman .
```

Comment: or `.replace(/!/g, '.')`

Answer (score 0):

There are better approaches to the problem. But for academic purposes, if you want to fix your algorithm:

Your `arr = str.toString()` is not converting the string to an array. Use `.split("")` and `.join("")` instead.

Also, clean your code in general :)

```js
const MyFunc = (str) => {
  let arr = str.split("");

  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    arr[i] = arr[i].replace('!', '.');
  }

  return arr.join("");
}

console.log(MyFunc('Mening yurtim ! Men juda faxirlanaman !'));
```